# Need to make a .bat which login on several wesites and check if they are working fine or not?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, automation

I need to automate a manual process in which a user need to login on several wesite with specific username and password and also checks some links(shared locations). If everything is normal then user send a mail to the specific group in table format.
Can anyone give me any idea, how to start the automation process. I am thinking of using .bat and .vbs.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your best bet is to use cURL.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

- Set up a headless Ubuntu machine (either on-premise or in the cloud)
- Install [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)
- Get familiar with creating Jenkins jobs and configuring them to email your group upon success or failure
- Install the [PhantomJS web browser](http://phantomjs.org/) on the Ubuntu box
- Use the [Python Selenium bindings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium%20%22Python%20Selenium%20bindings) to write a web automation script that uses PhantomJS to perform your web tests
- Finally, create a Jenkins job that runs that test script and emails you the results

With that infrastructure in place, you'll have a solution for the task at hand, and a foundation on which you can build many more tests and processes.

If you have a hard requirement to use Windows and .bat files, you can do that too - just install Jenkins on a Windows machine and configure your Jenkins jobs to execute batch commands. I still recommend using Python even if running on Windows, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think bat won't help you because it can't actually interact with a browser e.g. to enter username and password.

I'd go with [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site). It's simple and powerfull and has a nice [framework for browser interaction](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/IE%20Management.htm).

If you want to use something complicated but really powerfull (C#), check the [white framework by teststack](http://www.teststack.net/White).